# How to post model together with embedded model using Loopback.js?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Here is the form model schema:

```
{
  "startTime": "",
  "stopTime": "",
  "id": "objectid",
  "formQuestions": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "label": "",
      "content": [
        ""
      ],
      "id": "objectid"
    }
  ]
}
```

relations of form.json:

```
  "relations": {    
    "questions": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "FormQuestion",
      "option": {
        "validate": true,
        "autoId": true
      }
    }
  }
```

If I post to http://localhost:3000/api/Forms as follow,

```
{
  "startTime": "",
  "stopTime": "",  
  "formQuestions": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "label": "a label",
      "content": ["the content"]
    }
  ]
}
```

it returns:

```
{
  "startTime": "",
  "stopTime": "", 
  "id": "54ccf7ae6159f1bc0bc6b430",
  "formQuestions": []
}
```

But I want the embedded model formQuestion also to be inserted into the database, how can I do it? I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Did you create the `FormQuestion` model? Do you get any errors in the terminal?

Comment: @jakerella I find the way now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nobody knows, but I find the way myself.

It is because there is some bug about auto id generating with embedded document. It is useless even I set `autoId` to `true`. So if I post with manual id, it will success.

Just like this:

```
{
  "startTime": "",
  "stopTime": "",  
  "formQuestions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": 0,
      "label": "a label",
      "content": ["the content"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you try passing in `id: 0` ? It may be that the embedded object needs to have an `id` property, but if it is `0` maybe the system will auto generate?

Comment: No, it won't. I have tried to post `"id": 0`, but it just added a document whose id is 0. @jakerella

Comment: are you really need the id inside the embeded document? if you want to refere to this embeded document, you can give the parent document an "Id" and then refer to your embeded document with ParentId and index of embeded document in array.. just a work around!